# android and apple : Redirect to website for payment when cross platform services

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

**Description of the situation**:

- ***Application A:*** Purchases availables with in-app-purchase. Android & Apple.
- ***Website***: (in project). Offers different services than application A but is linked to the application. (for example a user of the website can see the usage statistics of some users of the application A, send them a message or send them activities to do). Use of Stripe on the site to access the paid features.
- ***Application B*** : (in project). We want to simplify the access to the website and therefore allow the access to some of the website features on the mobile application. The features can also be purchased with in app purchase from the app. Android & Apple.
- Application A will redirect to the website.
- The website will redirect to the application B.
- Application B will never redirect to the website.

**Question N°1**:
According to article 3.1.3(b) of the apple guidelines, since it is a cross platform service, we have the possibility to offer other payment methods than in app purchase in other platforms as long as they are available with in app purchase on the mobile application (which is our case). **Is it possible with android too?**

> 3.1.3(b) Cross-Platform Services: Apps that run on multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or features they have acquired in your app on other platforms or on your website, including consumable items in cross-platform games, provided that **these items are also available as in-app purchases in the app**.
> https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

**Question N°2** :
The redirection to another service that contains payment methods is normally forbidden on Apple and Android.
Since the redirection is made from an application to another totally different site, whose services are not accessible from the application A, is it in my right to make this redirection ? (**Application A → website**).

Thanks

---

**EDIT** :
I asked the question to the google service. Here is the answer which is unfortunately not very helpful:

> Unfortunately I'm not able to comment on your planned implementation. If you think your app is in compliance, please submit your app for another review. You may want to review the Developer Program Policies for additional policy guidance.
> https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

Apple asks you to offer in-app purchases if there are features unlockable in the app (which looks like you already have)

Google is the same, but the truth is they are much less strict than Apple on that.

Redirecting to a website from your app isn’t an issue. Even if the website has some paying features.
Redirecting to Application B from the website isn’t an issue either.

Side note: some of your users will be redirected from Application A to the website and then to Application B: which looks like to me that you will be loosing traffic from Application A towards Application B.

Comment: Thank you for these informations.

Do you know where I can find in the google terms and conditions a text that attests to this in the same way as the Apple quote that I put above? 
I would like to have a proof that they allow this in case their service blocks my application.

I will indeed lose some traffic, but the most important thing is the website not the app B so it is desired 

Comment: I don't have the Google Terms saying that they are less strict. I said it by experience ;)